# Android - startForeground action not showing

Tags: android, service

I'm currently trying to create a foregroundNotification with an action, but the action + icon won't show.

Here's my code:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(KEY);
        PendingIntent nextIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

        // Build the notification that tells the user that the service
        // is ongoing
        NotificationCompat.Builder foregroundNoteBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(....)
                .setContentTitle(....)
                .setContentText(....)
                .addAction(R.drawable.pause, "Pause all messages", nextIntent);

        Notification note = foregroundNoteBuilder.build();

        // Update the notification
        startForeground(1, note);
```

The foreground notification shows without the action. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Edit: 
Apparently this is occurring when any other notification is present in the notification tray (E.g. "Searching using GPS...", "Connected as a media device", etc.). Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: Can you please post your whole code i.e startForeground() method implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Action is not showing, because the notification is probably not expanded. Expand it by swiping/scrolling it down with two fingers.